# Why doesn't changing the color of link work?

Tags: css

I have stated the .topics:link in CSS but the color is still blue.

HTML is -

```
<ul class="topics">
     <li><a href="#">United States</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS is -

```
.topics:link {
color: #666665;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `:link` wrong. Use `.topics a` instead:

```
.topics a {
    color: #666665;
}
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for `.topics a:link` (to color a unvisited link)

Answer (score 1):

`.topics a{
color:#666665;
}`
Use this

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to change the color of text in `<a>` tag then use this

`.topics a { color: #666665;}`

The :link selector is used to select unvisited links.

like

`a:link
{ 
background-color:yellow;
}`

these are some pseudo class of a tag

```
a:link    {color:green;}
a:visited {color:green;}
a:hover   {color:red;}
a:active  {color:yellow;}
```